# Mysql count for distinct type

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table in a MySQL DB, hosts and `events`, that can join thanks and `ID` field. 
A particular field of interest for my query is, for `hosts` table, `name`; for the `events`, `type`. 
If I make a join between them, an example result is:

[image]

So, in this image, you can see for example that the Host Achille ha 4 events: 2 of OS type, 1 of Application time and 1 of Service Type.

My question is: using aggregator operators, is it possible to make a tabel where, for every host, i can show how many events there are divided by type?
More speficically, the desired table may have this header:

[image]

that, in aour previuos example, may return:

```
| Achille | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Aiace   | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Ulisse  | 0 | 0 | 1 |
```

My first try is this query:

```
    SELECT hosts.name, count(e1.type) as Applications, count(e2.type) as OS, count(e3.type) as Type 
    FROM hosts JOIN events e1 ON hosts.id = e1.host_id 
    JOIN events e2 ON hosts.id = e2.host_id 
    JOIN events e3 ON hosts.id = e3.host_id 
    WHERE e1.type = 'Applications' AND e2.type = 'OS' AND e3.type = 'Services' 
GROUP BY hosts.name;
```

but does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to join the events table multiple times. Just do conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT h.name, 
    count(case when e.type = 'Applications' then 1 end) as Applications,
    count(case when e.type = 'OS' then 1 end) as OS,
    count(case when e.type = 'Services' then 1 end) as Services
FROM hosts h
JOIN events e ON h.id = e.host_id 
GROUP BY h.name;
```

or concisely, using `sum`

```
SELECT h.name, 
    sum(e.type = 'Applications') as Applications,
    sum(e.type = 'OS') as OS,
    sum(e.type = 'Services') as Services
FROM hosts h
JOIN events e ON h.id = e.host_id 
GROUP BY h.name;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. But i must admit my ignorance; we have the case option in sql? Or is PLSQL? and what is the effect of the then 1 end instruction?

Comment: The `CASE` is a sql keyword. The 1 is just a non null value, you can write any non null value there. Here, the case returns 1 when condition is satisfied and null when not. The count function only counts non nulls

Comment: FYI, MySQL automatically treats true as 1 and false as 0, when those values are interpreted in a numeric context, so you should be able to shorten that to just `count(e.type = 'Applications') as Applications` (If you prefer the brevity; using a longer form that makes it more obvious on first glance what is going on, isn’t “wrong” of course.)

Comment: @CBroe - Yes agreed. but we need to use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` in that case, Added the edit

Comment: Thanks both of you for answer!

Comment: @GurwinderSingh you’re totally right of course, it needs to be SUM in that case, thanks!